# outputting a different value in report

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have 100+ feature files that each year need to be updated with the year of the request ie this year they show 22-23 but next it will be 23-24 in almost every test. We created a step that allowed us to us a variable instead that we set in config eg

currentYear: 22-23

which we can then manipulate in our step to use currentYear+1 currentYear-5 etc. This all works fine and means that annually we simply change the config however on the output it shows the variable name rather than the value...eg

And Path Parameters:
year: [currentYear]

What I need it to do is show that as the value it actually used.
year: 22-23

No doubt this is something simple but I can't quite seem to get it! Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Scenarios are examples, do your examples really have to change every year even if nothing else changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven you can filter resources before they're used in a test. This would allow you to use a variable in your feature files and have it replaced when tests are executed.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

I'm certain Gradle has a similar feature.

Note that these filtered resources will be put on the classpath. So you should use `classpath:com/example.feature` as your feature path and not `src/main/resources/com/example.feature`. If JUnit 5 is used `@SelectClasspathResource("com/example.feature")`.